# How do I delete the command message?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

**Hello.**

So, I'm currently trying to make a command that when you post the command, the command will get deleted and the content of the command will be posted.

Take this code for example:

```py
@client.command()
async def hello(ctx):
    await ctx.send("Goodbye!")
    await ctx.author.message.delte()
```

So, what I want to happen is for the `!hello` command to be deleted, while the Goodbye! message is being sent.

I tried with the message parameter, but it didn't work.

How can I do this?
**Thank you beforehand.**

Comment: Don't you have a typo? await `ctx.author.message.delte()` `delete()`

Comment: Try just `await ctx.message.delete()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @moinierer3000 said, you should use `await ctx.message.delete()`. You made a typo and the author attribute of Context does not have a message attribute.